# Bitnami Redmine + Support_helpdesk plugin codepage problems

Tags: redmine, bitnami

I'm trying to install support_helpdesk plugin (https://github.com/pvdvreede/support_helpdesk) on bitnami-redmine-2.3.1-3-ubuntu-12.04. What I did:

```
cd /opt/bitnami/apps/redmine/htdocs
git clone git://github.com/pvdvreede/support_helpdesk.git plugins/support_helpdesk
bundle install
rake db:migrate_plugins RAILS_ENV=production (there was an error about redis)
wget http://redis.googlecode.com/files/redis-2.6.14.tar.gz
tar xzf redis-2.6.14.tar.gz
cd redis-2.6.14
make  
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install tcl8.5 (redis doesn't work without this module)
make test (no errors after that)
/src/redis-server
```

in another ssh windows type
`cd /opt/bitnami/apps/redmine/htdocs 
rake redmine:plugins:migrate

/opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh restart apache`

And after that I can't open my http://my.host/redmine/ with error:

We're sorry, but something went wrong. We've been notified about this issue and we'll take a look at it shortly.

What should I try to fix this problem ? Appreciate any help, thank you in advance.

Answer:

fixed by using bundle install --deployment and using redmine 2.2.4, on 2.3.1 can starts normally, but after loading, can't create new issue witt error accessing to db.

Another problem is using non-english language in fetched email's body will cause unreadably symbols in issue body, ex. ������������, emails fetching in bellow module, any ideas how to fix ?

```
    require "#{File.dirname(__FILE__)}/../spec_helper"
    describe Support::Participants::CreateIssueBody do
      let(:participant) { Support::Participants::CreateIssueBody.new }
      let(:plain_basic_email) do
        Mail::Message.new(File.read(File.join(email_dir, "plain_basic.eml")))
      end
      let(:multi_basic_email) do
        Mail::Message.new(File.read(File.join(email_dir, "multi_basic.eml")))
      end
      let(:html_basic_email) do
        Mail::Message.new(File.read(File.join(email_dir, "html_basic.eml")))
      end
      before do
        participant.extend Support::Spec::Reply
        $reply = nil
        participant.workitem = workitem
      end
      context 'when there is plain text only' do
        let(:workitem) do
          create_workitem({
            'email' => plain_basic_email.to_yaml
          })
        end
        it 'will set the body as plain text' do
          participant.on_workitem
          $reply.fields['email_body'].should eq "Plain email.\n\nHope it works well!\n\nMikel"
        end
      end
      context 'when there is html only' do
        let(:workitem) do
          create_workitem({
            'email' => html_basic_email.to_yaml
          })
        end
        it 'will set the body to say it cannot render the body' do
          participant.on_workitem
          $reply.fields['email_body'].should eq "Cannot add body, please open attached email file."
        end
      end
      context 'when there is multipart' do
        let(:workitem) do
          create_workitem({
            'email' => multi_basic_email.to_yaml
          })
        end
        it 'will set the body as the plain text body' do
          participant.on_workitem
          $reply.fields['email_body'].should eq "This is a test *multi part* email.\n\nRegards,\n\nPaul."
        end
      end
      context 'when the email has Chinese characters' do
      end
    end
```

Comment: fixed by using bundle install --deployment and using redmine 2.2.4, on 2.3.1 can starts normally, but after loading, can't create new issue witt error accessing to db.

Comment: post your answer as an answer, not as part of the question. also make one question per issue.

Answer (score 2):

Fixed by using 'bundle install --deployment' and using Redmine 2.2.4. Starts normally now, but after loading, I can't create new issue with error accessing to db.